# NHibernate mapping inheritance with multiple level (Ambiguous mapping)

Tags: c#, nhibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have a big table like that :

```
TableA:
  -ID (PK)
  -CA1
  -CA2
  -CA3
  -CA4
  ...
  -CA9

TableB
  -ID(PK,FK TableA)
  -CB1
```

My classes :

Just some TableA columns

```
public abstract class Base
{
    public virtual string CA1 { get; set; }
    public virtual string CA2 { get; set; }
    public virtual string CA3 { get; set; }
}
```

Some more TableA columns

```
public abstract class Base2 : Base
{
    public virtual string CA4 { get; set; }
}
```

All Base2 properties, plus TableB (Concrete class)

```
public class ClassB : Base2
{
    public virtual string CB1 { get; set; }
}
```

What I tried (with mapping by code) :

```
public class BaseOverride : IOverride
{
    public void Override(ModelMapper mapper)
    {
        mapper.Class<Base>(m =>
        {
            m.Table("TableA");

            m.Id(x => x.Id, map =>
            {
                map.Column("Id");map.Generator(Generators.Identity);
            });

            m.Discriminator(x =>
            {
                x.Column("Base2");
            });
            ...
    }}

public class Base2Override : IOverride
{
    public void Override(ModelMapper mapper)
    {
        mapper.Subclass<Base2>(j =>
        {
            j.DiscriminatorValue("Base2");
            j.Property(x => x.CB1);
        });
    }
}

public class ClassBOverride : IOverride
{
    public void Override(ModelMapper mapper)
    {
        mapper.JoinedSubclass<ClassB>(map =>
        {
            map.Table("TableB");
            map.Key(key => key.Column("ID"));
            ...
        });
    }
 }
```

I got an error :

```
Ambiguous mapping of ClassB. It was registered with more than one class-hierarchy strategy
```

I know I´m using two hierarchy strategy here ... Is it posible to resolve that?

Thanks

Comment: Why not just map each table independently with references to each other? Then you can have a combined viewmodel for your purposes.